# how i get an user status and i give him a specific role, i tried but it doesn't work

Tags: discord

```html
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("-test"):
        await message.channel.send("Checking for the Status :pencil:..")
        time.sleep(1)
        async def on_member_update(before, after):
            if str("discord.gg / discord") in member.activities[0].name():
                print("Correct Status giving role to User")
                guild = client.get_guild(8516587165187561)
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=9157981598717517571)
                await message.channel.send("roled")
```

i try to get an user status and if he have that status specified he get the role, i don't know why it doesn't work, i use discord.py

Comment: can someone help pls

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to put `on_member_update` in the code. It wouldn't work anyway even if you do due to the fact it's an event function, not something you can call on.

```python
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("-test"):
        await message.channel.send("Checking for the Status :pencil:..")
        time.sleep(1)
        if str("discord.gg / discord") in message.author.activities[0].name():
            print("Correct Status giving role to User")
            guild = client.get_guild(8516587165187561)
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=9157981598717517571)
            await message.author.add_roles(role)
            await message.channel.send("roled")
```

I've also added the `await message.author.add_roles(role)` part because there wasn't any command that assign roles in your original code.